# Switch Active Class Based on ID of Link Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a one page layout with urls in the navigation like this,

```
www.myWebsite.com/#ID
```

When the page loads all of my links are staying active.
I need to remove the active class from all the links but the home link. 
Then switch the active class based on the `ID` of the section that has been clicked.

So when you click a link it scrolls to that section of the page and the active class switches to that specific link.

I tried this but get no errors and no luck. All links stay active and do not switch.

I wrapped the function cause this is a wordpress site.

```
 (function($){  
        $(function() {
            $('li a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
  })(jQuery);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your inner function is actually a `document.ready()` equivalent (which is apparently already inside `document.ready()`)

Comment: Ya my brother just said that too. I removed it but it still wont work. :(

Answer (score 0):

This works:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/oo2te3v2/)

```
$(function() {
  $('li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: In that JSFiddle if you click a link only that gets the active class

Comment: But the problem is all the links are active on page load. Your fiddle does not share this characteristic.

Comment: No, at load nothing has active class, where do you see it?